# Control over wcf proxy class name generated using svcutil.exe

Tags: wcf, class, proxy, svcutil.exe

Is there a simple command line switch or a trick to renaming the generated class name when running svcutil.exe to generate a client proxy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the namespaces (there is a flag for that)
if you want to use another name for a class, you can use the name attribute with the DataMember/DataContract Attribute, but not from svcutil.